# How can I backup everything from iCloud Photo Library on Windows?

Tags: icloud, photos

I don't want to pay Apple any more to upgrade my iCloud storage, so I want to clean-up the photos that are stored with iCloud Photo Library. I cannot find any way to download and backup my photos easily so that I can delete them from my cloud storage.

From Apples website:

> If you enabled iCloud Photo Library, your photos and videos are
>   automatically uploaded to iCloud at full resolution. To make copies of
>   these photos and videos:

- In iOS 8 or later, select Download and Keep Originals, then import the photos to your computer.
- In OS X Yosemite v10.10.3 or later, open the Photos app, then select Download and Keep Originals.
- Use iCloud.com to download the most recent version of photos and videos to your computer.

So, obviously I've tried the last option, but if one selects multiple photos and then click **Download**, it downloads all the files at the same time with garbage file names and without file extensions! You have to manually rename every file and guess the extension (usually .jpg for photos and .mp4 or .mov for videos).

Is there a better way to get a copy of my photos? The first option won't work because I have 20 GB of photos and my iPhone doesn't have room. The second option won't work for me because I don't have a Mac.